# How to unhide Wix Icon during a bundled installer?

Tags: wix, burn, wix4

I have created an installer bundle using WiX Burn but am having an issue where the installer does not present any sort of taskbar icon during the install process.  This makes it so clicking out of the window during the install makes it very hard to find the installer window again.

Edit: Also probably worth mentioning I am using WixV4 and building in VisualStudio.

I think it is important to note I am using an MSI's internal UI.
When I created a bundle without any custom UI, I recall it loaded a taskbar icon so I can only assume it has to do with using an MSI's internal UI.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" xmlns:util="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/util">
<?include ../Version.wxi ?>
<Bundle Name="Serverbundle"  Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="company" UpgradeCode="SOMEGUID">
    <BootstrapperApplication>
    <WixInternalUIBootstrapperApplication xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal"  />
    </BootstrapperApplication>
    <util:RegistrySearch Variable="PostGREInstalled" Id="Postgre_RegKey" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-15\" Result="exists" Bitness="always64" />
    <util:RegistrySearch Variable="HostBundleInstalled" Id="HostBundle_RegKey" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Updates\.NET\Microsoft .NET 6.0.20 - Windows Server Hosting (x86)\" Result="exists" Bitness="always64" />
    <Chain>
        <!--Install Prerequisites (IIS)-->
        <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.Prerequisites.TargetDir)$(var.Prerequisites.TargetName).msi" Permanent="yes" Visible="false"/>
        <!-- Install dotnet 3.1 hosting bundle-->
        <ExePackage SourceFile="./dotnet-hosting-6.0.20-win.exe" DetectCondition="HostBundleInstalled" Permanent="yes" DownloadUrl="https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/d7124775-38c9-460f-a269-7bc131b3dfbf/7f60bcc6030e408cf11a935d5451ffa4/dotnet-hosting-6.0.20-win.exe"  InstallArguments="/passive"/>
        <!-- Install Postgresql-->
        <ExePackage SourceFile="./postgresql-15.2-2-windows-x64.exe" DetectCondition="PostGREInstalled" Permanent="yes" DownloadUrl="https://sbp.enterprisedb.com/getfile.jsp?fileid=1258478" InstallArguments="--mode unattended --unattendedmodeui minimal" />
        <!-- Install BluefinServerDFE-->
        <MsiPackage SourceFile="INTERNALUI.msi"/>
    </Chain>
</Bundle>
```

I assume there is probably some sort of flag or variable I need to set; but google searching ends up pulling up results all having to do with shortcuts not appearing on the taskbar itself.  I want to be clear, my issue is that I have no taskbar icon appearing during the install process, so if I lose focus of the installer window, it gets buried in the background and is hard to locate.  Hopeful it's just a simple setting I'm missing but if anybody has any ideas I'm all ears.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be hitting on this issue:

https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/7874

There's no 100% workaround known yet. Specifying a SplashScreenSourceFile helps alot but not 100%.

Comment: I appreciate the reply but this does not seem to be the same issue I am seeing.  While it is similar (where the page goes to the back) my bundle doesn't even create a taskbar icon while the Bundle is installing.  Adding the suggested SplashScreenSourceFile did not change whether a taskbar icon appears.